# Unable to create scheduled Teams meeting with beta API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm trying to create a scheduled meeting following the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http).

Whilst I can create a meetNow meeting successfully, I cannot create a scheduled one.  Here's an example:

`POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/app/onlineMeetings`

```
{
  "meetingType": "scheduled",
  "startDateTime": "2020-02-01T09:00:00Z",
    "endDateTime": "2020-02-01T10:00:00Z",
  "participants": {
    "organizer": {
      "identity": {
        "user": {
          "id": "<user-id>"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "subject": "Test Scheduled Meeting"
}
```

I get this (truncated for brevity) response:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#app/onlineMeetings/$entity",
    "creationDateTime": "2020-01-31T10:00:27.4726306Z",
    "startDateTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "endDateTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "subject": "Test Scheduled Meeting"
}
```

This is the same response given when meetingType is set to meetNow which implies that scheduled is not currently supported.  Is this the case, and if so, anyone know when is it likely to be supported?

Answer (score 0):

Creating Scheduled meeting is not implemented in beta API yet. Currently scheduled works for GET API.

Comment: Subhasish - thanks for the reply.  Do you know if there is a timeline on when scheduled meetings will be supported?

Comment: @DonallBurns, There is no timeline fixed yet. You can certainly provide a feature request [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/feedback)